# Tabulator: can't have callback working when I move row between tables

Tags: tabulator

I'm using the latest version of Tabulator and it's a great library.
I'm having a problem when I try to move rows between tables having a callback after the row is sent

This is the [Row Movement Cycle](https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/move#rows-table-lifecycle) and I would use the *movableRowsSent* callback

Sending table

```
var table_user = new Tabulator("#user-table", {
layout:"fitColumns",
height:311,
movableRows:true,
movableRowsConnectedTables:"#amb-table",
movableRowsReceiver: "add",
movableRowsSender: "delete",
movableRowsSent: test(),
placeholder:"Utenti",
data:tabledata(),
columns:[
    { title: "Utenti disponibili", field: "username" },
],
ajaxConfig:{
    headers: {
      'X-WP-Nonce': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ); ?>'
    },
}
});
```

Receiving table

```
var table_amb = new Tabulator("#amb-table", {
height:311,
layout:"fitColumns",
movableRows:true,
placeholder:"Trascina qui",
data:[],
columns:[
    {title:"Ambiente x", field:"username", minWidth:240},
],
});
```

the simple test function

```
function test(){
    alert('ciao');
}
```

If I use this code the alert shows instantly, not after moving rows. Why?

Comment: I didn't test it but I assume you should provide a callback without `()`, i.e., `movableRowsSent: test,`, so provide only the name of the function instead of a call to the function.

Comment: You got it! It was so simple! Thanks a lot